# PHP replace content in a string

Tags: php, replace

I want to change the string "T Shirts Vests" into "TShirts Vests". I have tried this:

```
$item['menu_3'] = str_ireplace("T Shirts Vests", "TShirts", $item['menu_3']);
```

But `str_ireplace` doesn't seem to be able to handle that. How should I do this?

Comment: What is the output you are getting? And why are you using str_ireplace rather than str_replace? Do you need the case insensitivity?

Comment: The code you've typed makes perfect sense and works without error, except that you're replacing the *entire* string "T Shirts Vests" with "TShirts". We can't help you without knowing the content of `$item['menu_3'])`. Please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$item['menu_3'] = str_ireplace("T Shirts Vests","TShirts Vests", $item['menu_3']);
```

`str_replace` will work fine too by the way.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I dont want vests. Never the less this dosent work :( But If I replace just one word, eg. Shirts, it works

Comment: I'm not sure .. `str_replace` really just does that. It could fail if a character is not what you expect it to be. Like, there could be an invisible character in the string.

Comment: Checked the database and cant see any hidden characters :/

Comment: That's the point of hidden characters :P Loop over each character and print the character code.

Comment: Again. Until you *tell us* what the contents of `$item['menu_3']` are, we cannot help you. Please `var_dump($item['menu_3'])` and *update your question to include the output*.

Comment: The content is "T Shirts Vests"

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "T Shirts Vests";
$str[strpos($str, " ")] = '';
```

Comment: This will replace every space, so `T Shirts Vests` becomes `TShirtsVests`, which I don't think is what he's after.

Comment: thx @Sam, I initially thought the last parameter to str_replace (count) told PHP to stop at a certain number of replacements. But in fact, this is a variable you hand into the function that gets *set*. Fixed.